# Multiple queries in stored procedure not working in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, stored-procedures

Need to fetch all rows from 3 tables where current status =1

```
$query =  $this->db->query("CALL GetALLDetails('1')");
$result = $query->result_array();
print_r($result);
```

Stored Procedure:-

```
BEGIN
 select * from table1 where current_status = status;
 select * from table2 where current_status = status;
 select * from table3 where current_status = status;
END
```

Am getting result of first query statement only.

Comment: Maybe use transactions?

Comment: @KUMAR may i confirm whether my scenario is possible in CodeIgniter? Actually i need to use stored procedure.Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->db->trans_start();
$this->db->query('AN SQL QUERY...');
$this->db->query('ANOTHER SQL QUERY...');
$this->db->query('AND YET ANOTHER SQL  QUERY...');
$this->db->trans_complete();
```

**Note:-** For more about transactions

- [`transactions`](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/transactions.html)

Comment: He is asking about how to handle it in stored procedure, not in the transaction!